# Testing load document functionality with JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I am testing a service that has "load document" functionality. I need to send a unique document with every request. In the HTTP request sampler config menu I see that I can send a document along with my request. However, I don't have a clue as to how I am going to send a different document with every request. Is there a way to get JMeter to either slightly modify a document, generate a specified document, or even perhaps select a series of externally generated documents for submission with a request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use CSV Data Set Config under While Controller to read and send pre-created test documents names in cycle.

This will look like:

1. create collection of different test-documents to send with your request;
   OPTIONALLY: store path to folder with created documents as jmeter variable - to use in script;
2. create list of test-documents;
   you can do this in BeanShell Sampler with code as shown below;
3. add While Controller to send test-documents in cycle;
   CSV Data Set Config to While Controller as child - to read test-documents names from list.

**Detailed:**

[image: BeanShell Sampler]

`${__javaScript("${testFile}"!="<EOF>",)}` - to read list till the end of file
[image: While Controller]

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

[image: HTTP Request]

BeanShell Sampler code to generate test-files list:

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

String contentList = params[0];
String testDataDir = params[1];

File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + testDataDir);
BufferedWriter out = null;

try {

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        throw new Exception ("Directory " + dir.getName() + " not found.");
    }

    File contentFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + contentList);

    if (contentFile.exists()) {
        contentFile.delete();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(contentFile, true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("CONTENT LIST:\n");

    if ((dir.exists()) && (dir.listFiles() != null) && (out != null)) {
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (contentFile.length() == 0) {
                out.write(f.getName());
            } else {
                out.write("\n" + f.getName());
            }

            out.flush();

            System.out.println("Content " + f.getName() + " added to " + contentFile.getName() + ".");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    IsSuccess = false;
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
finally {
    out.close();
}
```