# JMeter - File upload and file download scenario

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to do performance test a web page.
I have a scenario for uploading a file and downloading a file. I need to load test uploading file and downloading file scenarios.

Can any one help me how to achieve these using JMeter.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 13):

There are actually no difficulties in recording upload/download traffic with any HTTP sniffing tool and then emulate recorded requests in using JMeter.

In the simplest case you will get something like the following:

- Thread Group to setup number of test users and loops;
- **for upload**: 1 HTTP POST request with *Use multipart/form-data for POST = true* - to sent file as part of [request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request);
- **for download**: 1 HTTP GET request for download + [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener attached to it - to save requested file.

This will look like the following:

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = X
Loop Count = Y
  . . .
  UPLOAD HTTP Request
  Method = POST
  Use multipart/form-data for POST = true
  -- Send Files with Request -- section:
  File Path = ${testFile}
  Parameter Name = datafile
  MIME Type = ...
  . . .
  DOWNLOAD HTTP Request
  Method = GET
    Save Responses to a file
    Filename Prefix = downloadTest_
    Variable Name = testFile
  . . .
```

Here you can find sample script implemented for schema given above: [file-upload-download.jmx](https://github.com/aliesbelik/jmeter-samples/blob/main/stackoverflow/2015-04-15_file-upload-download.jmx).

---

The following posts may also appear useful:

- [Testing load document functionality with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046447/testing-load-document-functionality-with-jmeter/8048644#8048644)
- [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)
- [How to Test Image Upload Functionality With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-test-image-upload-functionality-jmeter)
- [JMeter Testing Multiple Random File Uploads](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2019/09/jmeter-multiple-random-file-uploads/)
- [Handling File Upload in JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/fileUploadInJMeter.html)

Comment: the link to the upload-download.jmx file seems broken.

Comment: @MCeviker, hosting server unavailable.