# Implementing document upload in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to test the upload document feature functionality of my application.
The request type is a http request.
Jmeter is not recording the upload feature functionality.

How can i record document upload sampler on jmeter & then simultaneously parameterize it for uploading documents from different logins?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to search first through jmeter-tagged questions?
Asked many times before.

This should work for you: [JMeter - File upload and file download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8793096/993246).