# Jmeter scenario- Find maximum cucurrent active users who can uploads files

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, load-testing

I am new to Jmeter testing. Last day my client asked me to test his website for load. I did a normal testing on it but now he wants a scenario where,

"I need to post both text & images with max no of concurrent users.
And also please do monitor the resource usage like how much Ram, CPU & Bandwidth consumption."

I need to find out how many active users can use the site cucurrently.

I referred this, [JMeter - File upload and file download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676249/jmeter-file-upload-and-file-download-scenario) but still I am not clear about it. May be because I am new to it.

But I need  to login to the URL inhouse.net/redmine 
Then I should go to the Home page inhouse.net/redmine/home 
and the update profile photo there

How can I do this through jmeter?

Can someone please help.

Thanks!
Shari

Answer (score 1):

Get the newest JMeter version from the site, and get JMeter plugins (Extras with Libs Set) from [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/). Once JMeter and the plugins are installed, you should take your time and read these:

1. [JMeter user manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html)
2. [JMeter best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. [About performance testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx)

The third one is really long, it should give you every detail on performance testing, use it only if something is not clear.

Then, you have to record your test steps (the http(s) requests from your browser that you want to simulate), a good guide on that is [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

For the scenario, I'ld use the ultimate thread group from JMeter plugins pack, and slowly increase the number of users from 1 to 1000. Measure how much time does it take for 1 thread (user) to complete the test steps. For example if 1 user takes 1 minute to finish, I'ld start a new thread every 1 minute, up to 1000. (check out timers for this).

You'll have to establish some KPIs, that reflect your needs, (in your case it's upload successful) check out the MSDN guide for more details on this. You'll have to implement these checks in your jmeter scenario (profile) using assertions, to determines if an upload was successful or not.

Don't forget to run your final test in command line mode. (with the -n paramter, no GUI)

For resource usage monitoring I recommend using [dstat.](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/)

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for that. However, I need to login also. I mean I need to login and then do the uploading. So when I check for multiple users, it might not work with the same session. What do you think?

Comment: I'm can't say I completely understand your issue. Create and test the profile with 1 user at first, then you can set higher user numbers when you feel that profile is done. You'll obviously need more usernames if you are going to simulate more users. Use the CSV Config element to read the username,password combinations while testing. http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config