# How to calculate Response Time taken to download/export a file using JMeter?

Tags: download, export, response

I am new to JMeter, Can someone guide me on how to perform below scenario using JMeter tool

Application Under Test: Web application (.aspx) with HTTPS protocol

Scenario: Need to calculate the time taken for exporting the available records in the application to excel file

Comment: The following post may helpful for you: [Jmeter file upload and download Scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676249/jmeter-file-upload-and-file-download-scenario)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to follow the steps given in the post. But looks like the link given in the post seems to be broken. Hence, I could not get full information on it.