# How to download a file in Jmeter with just the original file content?

Tags: json, jmeter, download

I'm working on functional testing of a REST API using Jmeter and JSON.  I've got file uploading working but I cant seem to get the file downloading to work in jmeter.  I'm saving the response as noted in this post: [JMeter - File upload and file download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676249/jmeter-file-upload-and-file-download-scenario?rq=1)

When I do this, I am getting close but not quite exactly what I need.  This is and example of what I am getting:

```
--0rVAdzesdQq7VrwJaRoYGm_UHdMD5nhi9_5w4u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api-test"; filename="LIBFILE1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Library File for Automated Smoke Test

This file is used to test file library upload for automated smoke tests.
--0rVAdzesdQq7VrwJaRoYGm_UHdMD5nhi9_5w4u--
```

How can I get the download to only save the file contents?  In this example, it should only be:

```
Library File for Automated Smoke Test

This file is used to test file library upload for automated smoke tests.
```

This is a simple textfile.  I would also like to download the other formats that I'm uploading including jpg, png, docx, pdf but it wont be right if it has this extra data coming with it.  I figure once I get a simple text file working, it will help me get the more difficult file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener will store the data you can observe in the "Response Data" tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. If you see these `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`, etc. headers as **response data** - most probably your upload wasn't successful as you should not be getting the headers this way.

I would recommend double checking that the same request being executed via browser or i.e. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) tool returns the same response and fix your JMeter script in case of differences.

See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for details on how to properly mimic file operations with JMeter.

---

Alternative way of saving response data into a file is using [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener), given you select "groovy" in the language dropdown you should be able to save the response using the following simple script:

```
new File("/path/to/your/file.txt").setBytes(prev.getResponseData())
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped.  You were right.  I had to upload it without any MIME type set and now I can download it without the extra stuff.